# ParseExceptions when using HQL file on HDInsight

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm following this tutorial http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-use-hive/ but have become stuck when changing the source of the query to use a file.

It all works happily when using `New-AzureHDInsightHiveJobDefinition -Query $queryString` but when I try `New-AzureHDInsightHiveJobDefinition -File "/example.hql"` with `example.hql` stored in the "root" of the blob container I get ExitCode 40000 and the following in standarderror:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/C:/apps/dist/hive-0.11.0.1.3.7.1-01293/conf/hive-log4j.properties
FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 character 'Ã?' not supported here
line 1:1 character 'Â»' not supported here
line 1:2 character 'Â¿' not supported here
```

Even when I deliberately misspell the hql filename the above error is still generated along with the expected file not found error so it's not the content of the hql that's causing the error.

I have not been able to find the hive-log4j.properties in the blob store to see if it's corrupt, I have torn down the HDInsight cluster and deleted the associated blob store and started again but ended up with the same result.

Would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to induce a similar error by putting a [Utf-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) encoded .hql file into blob storage and attempting to run it.  Try saving your example.hql file as 'ANSI' in Notepad (Open, the Save As and the encoding option is at the bottom of the dialog) and then copy it to blob storage and try again.

If the file is not found on Start-AzureHDInsightJob, then that cmdlet errors out and does not return a new AzureHDInsightJob object. If you had a previous instance of the result saved, then the subsequent Wait-AzureHDInsightJob and Get-AzureHDInsightJobOutput would be referring to a previous run, giving the illusion of the same error for the *not found* case.  That error should definitely indicate a problem reading an UTF-8 or Unicode file when one is not expected.

Comment: Thanks but I'm certain that it is not the contents of the hql.  I deliberately misnamed the hql file and got the same error along with a  file not found.

Comment: Are you getting the file error when you do `Start-AzureHDInsightJob`?  If the file is not found on Start-AzureHDInsightJob, then that cmdlet errors out and does not return a new `AzureHDInsightJob` object. If you had a previous instance of the result saved, then the subsequent Wait-AzureHDInsightJob and Get-AzureHDInsightJobOutput could be referring to a previous run.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Will experiment later this evening (UK time) thanks for replying!

Comment: That did the trick, residual corrupted file.  If you re-write your comment as an answer I'll give it a big green tick  :-)